# AppEngine + GCM

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I m trying to build a very simple application using Google app Engine,GCM and Android. I got the Eclipse plugin to create a simple Google AppEngine backend project to integrate with Android Client. When I try try to run the application, I am getting this exception  and I couldn't able to move forward. I already surfed the internet, but I didn't get much help. Followed this tutorial,

```
DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();
    endpoint.insertDeviceInfo(
        deviceInfo
            .setDeviceRegistrationID(registration)
            .setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setDeviceInformation(
                URLEncoder
                    .encode(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
                        + " "
                        + android.os.Build.PRODUCT,
                        "UTF-8"))).execute();
  }
```

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

Any thoughts or help is greatly appreciated...

```
 06-01 16:58:14.545: D/GCMBaseIntentService(6251): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bGUjtR-6HtiYBLQ0d4xwNxLeBOpuaTfjJhbLmsH5DUX7whMZ9W8GnHRDycp-AhWc67xGAAlcGQEQdMCNTLCj4N0b5zDIBfWa-e1okPaccwQ-ZMheyriA1_gkfs6XjIM_gO68181yToP7qGDgvXrJiVGPpBadHOd_X0Z9qFJEtYan4kaFls, error = null, unregistered = null
06-01 16:58:14.545: D/GCMRegistrar(6251): resetting backoff for com.google.android.gcm.demo.app
06-01 16:58:14.545: V/GCMRegistrar(6251): Saving regId on app version 1
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251): Exception received when attempting to register with server at https://gcmdemoramesh.appspot.com/_ah/api/
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251): Not Found
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:314)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1060)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService.onRegistered(GCMIntentService.java:167)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.handleRegistration(GCMBaseIntentService.java:251)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:153)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 16:58:16.757: E/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService(6251):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-01 16:58:16.837: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6251): Releasing wakelock
06-01 16:58:52.202: D/GestureDetector(6251): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 6 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-01 16:58:52.322: E/ViewRootImpl(6251): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-01 16:59:04.204: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(6835): Parent view is not a TextView
06-01 16:59:04.234: D/dalvikvm(6835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 6% free 17219K/18220K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
06-01 16:59:04.244: I/dalvikvm-heap(6835): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.985MB for 2359312-byte allocation
06-01 16:59:04.254: D/dalvikvm(6835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 19519K/20528K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
06-01 16:59:04.294: D/dalvikvm(6835): GC_CONCURRENT freed 50K, 6% free 19536K/20568K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 31ms
06-01 16:59:04.294: V/GCMRegistrar(6835): Is registered on server: false
06-01 16:59:04.294: I/GCMDemo(6835): registering device (regId = APA91bGUjtR-6HtiYBLQ0d4xwNxLeBOpuaTfjJhbLmsH5DUX7whMZ9W8GnHRDycp-AhWc67xGAAlcGQEQdMCNTLCj4N0b5zDIBfWa-e1okPaccwQ-ZMheyriA1_gkfs6XjIM_gO68181yToP7qGDgvXrJiVGPpBadHOd_X0Z9qFJEtYan4kaFls)
06-01 16:59:04.294: D/GCMDemo(6835): Attempt #1 to register
06-01 16:59:04.304: V/GCMDemo(6835): Posting 'regId=APA91bGUjtR-6HtiYBLQ0d4xwNxLeBOpuaTfjJhbLmsH5DUX7whMZ9W8GnHRDycp-AhWc67xGAAlcGQEQdMCNTLCj4N0b5zDIBfWa-e1okPaccwQ-ZMheyriA1_gkfs6XjIM_gO68181yToP7qGDgvXrJiVGPpBadHOd_X0Z9qFJEtYan4kaFls' to http://gcmdemoramesh.appspot.com//register
06-01 16:59:04.344: D/libEGL(6835): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-01 16:59:04.344: D/libEGL(6835): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-01 16:59:04.344: D/libEGL(6835): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-01 16:59:04.344: I/Adreno200-EGL(6835): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3544079)
06-01 16:59:04.344: I/Adreno200-EGL(6835): Build Date: 03/28/13 Thu
06-01 16:59:04.344: I/Adreno200-EGL(6835): Local Branch: adreno_20130328
06-01 16:59:04.344: I/Adreno200-EGL(6835): Remote Branch: 
06-01 16:59:04.344: I/Adreno200-EGL(6835): Local Patches: 
06-01 16:59:04.344: I/Adreno200-EGL(6835): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-01 16:59:04.394: D/OpenGLRenderer(6835): Enabling debug mode 0
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835): Failed to register on attempt 1
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835): java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 404
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ServerUtilities.post(ServerUtilities.java:169)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ServerUtilities.register(ServerUtilities.java:66)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity$2.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:79)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity$2.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:1)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-01 16:59:06.236: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 16:59:06.236: D/GCMDemo(6835): Sleeping for 2225 ms before retry
06-01 16:59:08.458: D/GCMDemo(6835): Attempt #2 to register
06-01 16:59:08.468: V/GCMDemo(6835): Posting 'regId=APA91bGUjtR-6HtiYBLQ0d4xwNxLeBOpuaTfjJhbLmsH5DUX7whMZ9W8GnHRDycp-AhWc67xGAAlcGQEQdMCNTLCj4N0b5zDIBfWa-e1okPaccwQ-ZMheyriA1_gkfs6XjIM_gO68181yToP7qGDgvXrJiVGPpBadHOd_X0Z9qFJEtYan4kaFls' to http://gcmdemoramesh.appspot.com//register
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835): Failed to register on attempt 2
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835): java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 404
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ServerUtilities.post(ServerUtilities.java:169)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ServerUtilities.register(ServerUtilities.java:66)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity$2.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:79)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity$2.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:1)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-01 16:59:09.028: E/GCMDemo(6835):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 16:59:09.028: D/GCMDemo(6835): Sleeping for 4450 ms before retry
06-01 16:59:13.483: D/GCMDemo(6835): Attempt #3 to register
06-01 16:59:13.493: V/GCMDemo(6835): Posting 'regId=APA91bGUjtR-6HtiYBLQ0d4xwNxLeBOpuaTfjJhbLmsH5DUX7whMZ9W8GnHRDycp-AhWc67xGAAlcGQEQdMCNTLCj4N0b5zDIBfWa-e1okPaccwQ-ZMheyriA1_gkfs6XjIM_gO68181yToP7qGDgvXrJiVGPpBadHOd_X0Z9qFJEtYan4kaFls' to http://gcmdemoramesh.appspot.com//register
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The issue was with the endpoint location in my Server project... It had my package name lakshmi.com instead of google.com. Once I changed it, it works fine...

Thank You all...